# Element Inspector in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

Hey, I accidentally closed that window in VS that you can use to inspect variables and the like, and I can't find anywhere to get it back; where do I find it? Thanks.

Comment: You mean Properties? or the Autos/Locals/Watch window?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

> Debug -> Windows -> Locals

It may be Immediate or Watch instead of Locals depending on what you are looking for.  You will need to be in the middle of a Debugging session for Locals or Watch to show up.